# Introductory analysis problem proving equalities with potentially an existence theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

$f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \hspace{0.5em} continous $ with $f(a)=b \hspace{0.5em} and \hspace{0.5em} f(x)f(f(x))=c \hspace{0.5em}\forall x\in [a,b], $ where $1<a<c<b $

Find $f(b) \hspace{0.3em} and \hspace{0.3em} f(c)$

I've tried approaching it with existential theorems but nothing useful comes up. And I can't see how to algebraically manipulate this. Maybe something like $ f(a)=b \Leftrightarrow f(f(a))=f(b) $and from that you almost get something in the form of $f(x)f(f(x))$.

Comment: Please make the subject line informative about the mathematical quesstion you are asking, not about what you.

Comment: This problem has a flaw, it seems. The hypotheses force $f$ to be defined on an interval strictly containing $[a,b]$. In particular, $f(b)= c/b < 1$, so $f(b)$ is not in the domain.

Comment: Yeah that's true is this problem just wrong then? Because I was wondering how $f(c)$ comes up

Comment: $f(c)=1$ if you resolve my domain concerns.